# Generate object form xsd file using pythons builtin xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xsd, elementtree

I got a bunch of xsd files from a third party app. Now I want to parse these files and create objects from those definitions so I can handle them easy (like myXSDObj.attr1 = myValue).

I know that there are many modules out there (lxml, PyXB,...) that do just that! But unfortunately I am limited to the built-ins of Python 2.7 and can't use other modules.

I thought of using etree, because is looks coder-friendly. But I could not find a way to create objects. The Element class does not seem to be an object where I could set the defined attributes. It seems to be, well, something else. I can set any attribute on an Element class, even if it is not defined in the xsd. Some code here:

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\censored\CustomerTypes.xsd')
root = tree.getroot()

for element in root.iter('{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType'):
    name = element.attrib.get('name')
    if name == "CustomerComType":
        for child in element:
            for baby in child:
                if baby.attrib.get('name') == 'UniqueReference':
                    break

baby.set('UniqueReference_MyBloodyTest', 'test')
print baby.attrib

#Result:
#{'UniqueReference_MyBloodyTest': 'test', 'type': 'customertypes:UniqueReferenceSimType', 'name': 'UniqueReference', 'minOccurs': '0'}
```

The result is not what I want. I wanted it to throw an error because there is no attribute 'UniqueReference_MyBloodyTest'. So I missunderstood that completely. 
Well...what should I say...
Should I keep trying with etree or should I try minidom? Years ago I once used minidom and I remember headache and a working piece of code in the end.

Comment: "*Should I keep trying with etree or should I try minidom?*" What exactly is your goal? As you noted, the parsed XSD file is not special; it is just like any other XML file with no restrictions on what attributes you can set etc. And that won't change if you use minidom (or lxml for that matter).

Comment: The XSD contains the definition of a class. Goal: I want to create instances of this class and set attributes on these instances. If I try to set an attribute that is not defined in the XSD, I want to get an attribute-error. Btw: For another task I consumed WSDLs (and thus XSDs) with SUDS. SUDS  gives me python-like objects that are very easy to work with. Now I would like to do the same, but with built-ins.

Comment: An XML Schema (XSD) file is just a normal XML file. If it is parsed into a Python object (an `ElementTree` instance, for example), there is nothing special about it. It does not provide any logic that tells you what attributes are valid or anything like that. If you explain WHY you need to create these instances, maybe someone can provide a suggestion.

Comment: I don't NEED to create these instances but I would like to do so. The class definitions are huge and complex. And eventually other coders will work with them too. So I thought that it would be more resistant to mistakes. But if it can't be done, I can manage without.Thanks mzin!